# Probability, approximation by simple functions, boundedness and non-negativity.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

In my probability class various results were announced requiring that a certain random variable was bounded. The specific example that interests me is the following: if $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and bounded, then
$$E(XY|G)=YE(X|G). \quad \quad (**) $$

where $E$ denotes expectation and $X$ is in $L^1$.

I found this result is used somewhere else but arguing that it is valid since $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$ and non-negative, or at least that is what I understood. This is not the first time I find an argument I studied for bounded functions that is used for non-negative functions without knowing if they are bounded.

The argument we used in class to prove this was not very detailed: we only proved it for indicator variables, which extends to simple variables by linearity of the expectation and then we said that it follows too for bounded functions by the *monotone convergence*. We never did this argument in full rigour.

> Is it true that for (**) non-negativity of $Y$ is a substitute for boundedness? Can someone clarify to me or point me to a reference about the exact approximation argument that uses
>   the monotone converge theorem to pass from simple functions to
>   non-negative or bounded functions?

Comment: 1. Do you know the monotone convergence theorem? 2. Do you know how to approximate measurable functions by simple functions?

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem: yes. But the approximation, I have never done it. I suppose that if a variable is bounded, then you approximate it from below with this simple functions that, I am understanding, are linear combinations of indicator variables. Then the fact that the function is bounded and that the sequence is increasing gives you by the monotone convergence theorem the existence of a limit. At least this is the argument I heard but I have never done it in detail. But what about for non-negative variables? That is where I get lost...

Comment: I just found the approximation construction. I see that one always approximates first the non-negative part. I remain a little bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approximation of non-negative measurable functions works as follows:

> **Sombrero lemma:** Let $(E,\mathcal{A})$ be measurable space and $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative mesasurable function. Then there exists a sequence of simple functions $(f_n)_n$ such that $0 \leq f_n \leq f$ and $f_n \uparrow f$ (i.e. $f_1(x) \leq f_2(x) \leq \dots$ and $\sup_n f_n(x) = f(x)$ for each $x$).

*Proof:* For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define

$$f_n(x) := \begin{cases} k 2^{-n}, & \text{if} \, x \in \{k 2^{-n} \leq f < (k+1) 2^n\} \, \text{for some} \, k \in \{0,\ldots,2^{2n}\} \\  2^n, & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$

so, basically, $f_n(x) = k 2^{-n}$ if $f(x) \in [k 2^{-n},(k+1) 2^{-n})$. Obviously, $f_n$ is a simple function, $f_n \leq f$ and $f_n \uparrow f$. This finishes the proof.

Literature: *René L. Schilling: Measures, Integrals and Martingales. Cambridge University Press, 2011.*

---

Now suppose that $Y \geq 0$ is $G$-measurable. By the Sombrero lemma, there exists a sequence of $G$-measurable simple functions $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $0 \leq Y_n \leq y$ and $Y_n \uparrow Y$. Recall that we know that the claim holds true for each $Y_n$ (since it is a simple function).

Suppose additionally that $X \geq 0$. Then it follows from the (conditional) monotone convergence theorem that

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(X Y \mid G) &= \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}(X Y_n \mid G) \\ &= \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Y_n \mathbb{E}(X \mid G) \\ &= Y \mathbb{E}(X \mid G). \tag{1} \end{align*}$$

For general $X \in L^1$, we write $X= X^+ -X^-$ where $X^+ := \max\{0,X\} \geq 0$ and $X^- := - \min\{0,X\} \geq 0$ denote the positive and negative part of $X$, respectively. Using the linearity of the expectiation, we get

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(X \mid G) &= \mathbb{E}(X^+ Y \mid G) - \mathbb{E}(X^- Y \mid G) \\ &\stackrel{(1)}{=} Y \mathbb{E}(X^+ \mid G) - Y \mathbb{E}(X^- \mid G) \\ &= Y \mathbb{E}(X \mid G). \tag{2} \end{align*}$$

Finally, if $Y \in L^1$ not necessarily non-negative we do the same trick again: Write $Y = Y^+ - Y^-$, apply $(2)$ to $$\mathbb{E}(X Y^+ \mid G) \qquad \text{and} \qquad \mathbb{E}(X Y^- \mid G)$$ and use the linearity of the expectation.

Comment: Hello @saz. Could you please detail why the sequence $f_n$ is increasing?